# Find row number in filter function result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a filter result I want to search for a date and return the row number (not sheet row, but row in the result)

My idea was to find it with Match, but it is not working.
See the picture to understand the problem.

I need this to make a formula to show the difference between the dates of "XY".
My approach is filter for XY, get the position of the date minus 1.

[image]

Comment: Not tested but your FILTER formula in column L returns a 2 dimensional array because first argument is `A4:B12`. Column A holds the texts and MATCH is searching there. So you are looking for a date in a range of cells with values like `xy, n, xy....` and there is no match. Try replacing `A4:B12` with `B4:B12` because it holds the dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter should only return column B:

`=MATCH(H3;FILTER(B4:B12;A4:A12="xY");0)`

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula-

```
=MATCH(H3,INDEX(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A4:B12,A4:A12="XY")),2),0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or using the same logic as the filter:

`=FILTER(ROW(A4:A12),A4:A12="XY")`